# How do I use python to turn two lists into a dictionary, and the value is the maximum value

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two lists here

```
L = ["a","b","b","c","c","c"]
L_02 = [1,3,2,4,6,""]
```

I want to turn two lists into a dictionary, and the value is the maximum value

```
dic = {"a":1,"b":3,"c":6}
```

how can I do this?

Comment: the 'maximum value' of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first get the indices of each element in the list, get the corresponding values in the second list, and find the maximums and make a dictionary.

```
dic = {}
for element in set(L):
    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(L) if x == element]
    corresponding = []
    for i in indices:
        if type(L_02[i]) == int:
            corresponding.append(L_02[i])
    value = max(corresponding)
    dic[element] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L = ["a","b","b","c","c","c"]
L_02 = [1,3,2,4,6,""]
return_dict = {}
for item1, item2 in list(zip(L,L_02)):
    if item1 not in return_dict:
        return_dict[item1] = item2
    elif isinstance(item2,int) and return_dict[item1] < item2:
        return_dict[item1] = item2
print(return_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 6}
```